# MySQL Error : 1422 Explicit and Implicit Commit is not allowed in SP and Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have Created a trigger, where I am storing some specific data in a table and after the trigger gets executed I am deleting that Table.

The query :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `afterinsert_Golden_Ball` AFTER INSERT ON `team_trophies` FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

    DECLARE badgeID INT(10);   

   CREATE TABLE tempname AS 
     (SELECT AVG(d.fair_play) as AvgPlay , b.tournament_id , d.* FROM 
     `team_trophies` a INNER JOIN tournament_scheduling b ON
      a.tournament_id = b.tournament_id INNER JOIN matches c ON b.id 
      = .match_id INNER JOIN user_match_result d ON c.id = d.match_id WHERE 
      a.tournament_id = 1 GROUP BY d.user_id);

  IF EXISTS (SELECT * from tempname WHERE AvgPlay = (SELECT MAX(AvgPlay) FROM tempname))    

  THEN

        SELECT badge_id INTO badgeId FROM badge_master WHERE name  = 'Golden Ball';

        Insert into user_badges(badges_id , user_id , match_id , turf_id ,
           tournament_id , created_date)
        SELECT  badgeID , user_id , match_id , NULL , tournament_id , 
           created_date from tempname limit 1;

   END IF;

   DROP TABLE tempname;

END
```

MySQL Error : 1422 Explicit and Implicit Commit is not allowed in SP and Trigger

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 0):

(Too much for a Comment...)  (Working backwards...)

`LIMIT 1`, but no `ORDER BY`??  You don't care which item you get?

`SELECT .. INTO badgeId`, but then don't really use it?  Perhaps the subsequent `SELECT` should have `WHERE name  = 'Golden Ball'`?

Instead of doing `IF EXISTS`, try to cause the final `SELECT` to return nothing.  That would have the same effect, and will probably eliminate the 'need' for a temp table.

Does that `IF EXISTS` do anything other then see if there are any rows in `tempname`??  If so please explain.

Is `d.user_id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of `team_trophies`?  If not, the `GROUP BY` may be improper.

No mention of `OLD.` or `NEW.`??

I suspect the `INSERT .. SELECT` could be simply use the original `SELECT`, plus an additional `WHERE` clause based 'Golden Ball', but I am too lost to attempt to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trigger, which is same as function could be called multiply time at unpredicted for You time

so the code like

```
CREATE TABLE tempname;

DROP TABLE tempname;
```

illegal for this type of code.

Just think what would be if 2nd session start insert at the same time? (100% realistic situation in any multi user environment)

For prevent collisions - this is not allowed.

Comment: The reason that it isn't allowed is because a `CREATE TABLE` does an (implicit) `COMMIT`. And we can't commit inside a trigger. Any actions that a trigger performs are committed (or rolled back) together with the action that triggered it.